# JSON Schema: Is there a field to specify meta data for a field?

Tags: javascript, json, user-interface, jsonschema

If I have JSON Schema such as:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/product.schema.json",
  "title": "Product",
  "description": "A product in the catalog",
  "type": "object"
}
```

Is there field defined in the JSON schema spec that allows me to add options? I am thinking of using the JSON schema itself to generate a UI form but I want to add an option for hiding the field. So I am thinking about doing something like:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/product.schema.json",
  "title": "Product",
  "description": "A product in the catalog",
  "type": "object",
  "options" : {
     "isVisible": false
   }
}
```

Is this valid JSON Schema or is there standard field I can use for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, JSON Schema evaluators will ignore keywords they don't recognize, so you are free to create new ones such as `options`.

However, there is a keyword for the purpose you describe here: `readOnly` and `writeOnly`: https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.9.4  Setting `"writeOnly": true` should indicate (to tools that support this keyword) that the property should never be visible.